# PHP Sessions not working in Internet Explorer, cookies are working great though

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, session-cookies

Im having trouble with sessions in IE. I have tested in IE 7-8, but it does not work in any of them. I can see that i am logged in, and then redirected, but the session is dropped somehow. It works great in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

If i use the "remember me" function i made, then it also works in IE ?! So it cant be a problem with cookies ?

I researched the problem a lot and found some forums where people suggested the following changes to config:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']        = 'cisession'; 
$config['sess_expiration']        = 72000;
```

This does not work either.

In the same forum, a guy says he found the solution in the local time:

> I’ve found the solution to my problem.
>   Apparently, IE7 drops sessions that
>   are set when your machine’s date and
>   time is not correctly configured.
>   Follow this link, No Cookies in IE??.
>   I hope it made your day as it made
>   mine.

The problem is that the link he refers to does not work.

Does anybody here have a clue on whats the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the local time incorrect on the machine where sessions don't work?

Comment: Im am not sure, how does i check this ?

Comment: open the system clock - on Windows, it's in the task bar usually

Comment: YES it actually was, hmm, now it's the right local time, but still not working. In the thread i refer to, they talk about the server has to match the local machine time, http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/90364/P45/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a php header redirect immediatly after setting the session? That has been an issue for me sometimes. Can be solved by doing a redirect with javascript on page load.

Comment: Yes i do, i just removed the header redirect, and it works and i get logged in and can see the "user menu", but when i click on a new page, im logged out again.. hmm

Comment: Do you have session_start() at the top of all your pages?

Comment: Yes, a header.php is included on all pages, in this the session_start(); is in the top

Comment: Well im stumped, usually a problem is hard to solve without being able to see the source - Hope someone else can provide some insight for you

Comment: Well I got a step closer to the fix, thank you for your time Mick